# NullPointerException for ExentTest when trying to log inside a @Test method

Tags: java, selenium, testng, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I've got a TestNG framework currently set up with Extent Reports and I'm using ITestListener to handle the reporting. It works fine, until I try to add logging for individual test steps inside my @Test methods.

I declare my ExtentTest 'test' in baseTests.java, and then initialise it in my onTestStart() listener, but 'test' is coming back as 'null' in my @Test.

I've tried moving the ExtentTest declaration around, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Is there a way of using the instance of test that's initialised in onTestStart()?

**baseTests.java**

```
package base;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

public class baseTests  {
    public ExtentReports extent = ExtentReporterNG.getReportObject();
    public ExtentTest test;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        // Test set-up code
    }
}
```

**ExtentReportNG.java**

```
package base;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter;

public class ExtentReporterNG {
    static public ExtentReports extent;
    public static ExtentReports getReportObject() {
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/reports/report.html";
        ExtentSparkReporter reporter = new ExtentSparkReporter(path);
        reporter.config().setReportName("Automation Tests");
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(reporter);
        return extent;
    }
}
```

**Listeners.java**

```
package base;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class Listeners extends baseTests implements ITestListener {

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        test = extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        test.log(Status.PASS, "Test Passed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        test.fail(result.getThrowable());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        extent.flush();
    }

}
```

**myTest.java**

```
package test;

import base.baseTests;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import pages.*;

public class myTest extends baseTests {

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        // Some test code
        test.log(Status.PASS, "Some test step");
        // Assert statement
    }
```

**Stack trace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest.log(com.aventstack.extentreports.Status, String)" because "this.test" is null

    at test.myTest.test1(myTest.java:15)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

Comment: I guess you are not initializing `ExtentTest test` in base class. `test.startTest("test name");`

Comment: @NandanA Thanks, unfortunately that doesn't seem to solve the problem. If I initialise ExtentTest at the start of baseTests.java (rather than in onTestStart) then only one test is created for the report - and it's still only logging the logs in listeners. I've also tried initalising ExtentTest in BeforeTest, but then I get NullPointerExceptions in my listeners. Ideally I want to keep my listeners as they keep things clean, but for some reason it's not letting me use the same instance of ExtentTest within my listeners and within my BeforeTest or Test methods, despite everything being public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to make ExtentTest static. Now the tests steps get logged to the tests just as I wanted.

```
public static ExtentTest test;
```